# Present perfect?

Tags: verbs, present-perfect, present-simple, irregular-forms

Is it correct to use ***have*** in this sentence?
“I ***have*** blocked all of them and I’d like you to do the same.”
If it is correct, why can’t I use it without *have*?

Comment: The present perfect indicates that the action was recently completed and has an effect on the current situation.

Comment: You can use it without *have*, though.  Did someone tell you that you couldn't?

Comment: No, but what’s the difference in meaning?

Comment: It's the same as the difference between the simple past and the present perfect anywhere else.  The simple past is about a completed action in the past.  The present perfect emphasizes the connection to the present, possibly as part of an ongoing process.  In this context there isn't really any difference in meaning.